# Publish message in queue RabbitMq not working , consumer read message randomnly

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm trying to work with RabbitMQ, my idea was to use an app with all the strate Controller Service +impl as a message producer and create a service to consume messages from my queue made with RbMQ, but unfortunately it's not working as it expected. The strange thing is that my message can be read by my consumer if i send it from the client when the trigger is almost ready to get the message, when im using my api from swagger also, but if i send a message it look like my queue don't receive anything at the client interface. Im lost can you help me please ?

Kind regards

here is my controller

```
package com.example.pattern.DataBroker.Api.Controller;

import com.example.pattern.DataBroker.Service.ServiceRB;
import com.example.pattern.DataBroker.Api.Dto.SupportDto;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

@RestController("Producer")
public class RabbitMqController {
    private ServiceRB serviceRB;

    public RabbitMqController(ServiceRB serviceRB) {
        this.serviceRB = serviceRB;
    }
    @PostMapping("Message")
    public ResponseEntity fillRabbitMQQueue(@RequestBody @Valid SupportDto dto) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        serviceRB.publishMessage(dto.getMessages());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

my serviceImpl producer

```
package com.example.pattern.DataBroker.Service.Impl;


import com.example.pattern.DataBroker.Service.ServiceRB;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

@Service
public class ServiceRBImpl implements ServiceRB {
    private final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "QueueTest";
    private final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "ProducerToQueue";
    private final ConsumeQueueImpl consumeQueue = new ConsumeQueueImpl();

    public ServiceRBImpl() {
    }

    public Channel createChannel() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        final var host = "localhost";
        connectionFactory.setHost(host);
       return connectionFactory.newConnection().createChannel();
    }

    public void publishMessage(List<String> messages) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        Channel channel = null;
        try {
            channel = createChannel();
            Channel finalChannel = channel;
            messages.stream().map(String::getBytes).forEach(messageBytes -> {
                try {
                    finalChannel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, QUEUE_NAME, null, messageBytes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
            // Compte des messages...
        } finally {
            if (channel != null && channel.isOpen()) {
                try {
                    channel.close();
                } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

here my consumer

```
package com.example.pattern.DataBroker.Service.Impl;

import com.example.pattern.DataBroker.Service.ConsumerQueue;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.DeliverCallback;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class ConsumeQueueImpl implements ConsumerQueue {
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "QueueTest";
    private final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "ProducerToQueue";

    @Override
    public void consumeMessages() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");

        try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
             Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null); // Déclaration de la file d'attente
            channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct", true); // Déclare l'échange avec la durabilité
            channel.queueBind(QUEUE_NAME, EXCHANGE_NAME, "");

            System.out.println("En attente de messages...");

            DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
                String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
                System.out.println("Message reçu : '" + message + "'");
            };
            channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {
            });
        }
    }

}
```

and my trigger

```
package com.example.pattern;

import com.example.pattern.DataBroker.Service.Impl.ConsumeQueueImpl;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PatternApplication {

    private final ConsumeQueueImpl consumeQueue = new ConsumeQueueImpl();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        SpringApplication.run(PatternApplication.class, args);
    }
        @PostConstruct
        public void scheduleMessageConsumption() {
            ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                try {
                    consumeQueue.consumeMessages();
                } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
```